# When GCC links a shared library is the soname stored?

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries

If you compile and link in a shared library does it store the soname of the library somewhere in the binary so it knows which one to link to? In other words if I link against a version 1.0.0 of liba.so and then I update my library to 2.0.0 and the ABI/API has changed and now my sym link to liba.so is pointing to the 2.0.0 version will the binary still know to look at liba.so.1? In other words does it store the specific soname of the linked library in the binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ldd` to view the dependency of a binary.

Try `ldd /bin/bash` yourself

On my machine it prints

> ```
> linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff10dff000)
> libncurses.so.5 => /lib/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007f2237acb000)
> libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f22378c7000)
> libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2237564000)
> /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2237d25000)
> ```